# "Thanks for the feedback!" modal hovering over website search bar at top

Tags: bug, design

It looks like the "Thanks for the feedback!" modal is at the wrong "hover" level. When it opens, if you scroll up, it appears over the website bar, covering the search bar, however it feels like it should be under. See screenshots below.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Go to a site that you aren't registered on and click a question (such as [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203060/why-did-stormtroopers-leave-their-stations-to-watch-lightsaber-duel-between-vade))
2. Upvote an answer, bringing up a popup saying "Thanks for the feedback!"[image]
3. Scroll up. See bug.[image]